# ECMAScript import { } from './somwhere.js'

Tags: javascript, import

I'm trying to fully understand JavaScript import and exports. According to the syntax diagram on https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-exports it's valid to have an empty block which I assume means import nothing so what is it for? Example:

```
import { } from './somewhere.js'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run the code in somewhere.js. That might be useful for initializing something, but if that's all you need, you can get the same effect with:

```
import './somewhere.js'
```

So i don't really see a reason to write the example you're asking about.

If i had to guess, i'd assume the reason it's allowed is that a definition allowing N named imports (eg, `import { foo, bar, baz } from './somewhere.js"`) would very easily have a base case of `import { } from './somewhere.js`, and there just wasn't a reason to ban the empty case.

Comment: Tnx. That's the conclusion I came to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take code bellow as our example

`./somewhere.js`

```
console.log('imported');

export const PI = 3;
```

Importing code above using `import { } from './somewhere.js'` will result in logging into console. The same would be true for `import './somewhere.js'`.